# Perl how to find motifs in a multi fasta file

Tags: perl, sequence

Given a multi fasta file named file.txt:

```
>seq1  
CCTTTGGATGGCAAAATTTNTNGTAAA
AGGGCACCCANTTCTGGC  
>seq2
NNNNNGGGGCGTAANGAGGGGCACGG
TNCC
>seq3   
AAAAAANNNNTAC
```

I want to find motifs matching with the pattern
[NC].[CT] (element N or C followed by any element . followed by an element C or T)
and
[AT][AN]..[CG] (element A or T followed element A or N followed by any two elements .. followed by an element C or G)
for each sequence starting with symbol '>' and count how many sequences contain the motif. The main problem I am encountering with this code is the iteration over each sequence. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;

if(!open(MY_HANDLE, "file.txt")){
    die "Cannot open the file";
}
 @content = <MY_HANDLE>;
close(MY_HANDLE);
foreach $row(@content){
  chomp($row);
     if (@matches1=$row =~ /([AT][AN]..[CG]+)/g)  {
     $numMat=scalar(@matches1);
     print("@matches1,$numMat\n");
     }
     elsif (@matches2=$row =~ /[NC].[CT]+/g)  {
     print("@matches2\n");
     }
  }
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

sub output {
    my ($id, $seq) = @_;
    my $count = () = $seq =~ /(?=[NC].[CT]|[AT][AN]..[CG])/g;
    say "$id\t$count" if $count;
}

my ($id, $seq);
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^>(\S*)/) {
        output($id, $seq) if defined $id;
        $id = $1;
        $seq = "";
    } else {
        $seq .= $_;
    }
}
output($id, $seq);
```

Process the file line by line. When you encounter a sequence header, remember the id, otherwise concatenate the sequence to its previous part - the pattern can match over a line boundary!

The `output` is called once more at the end, otherwise the last sequence wouldn't have been processed.

I used a look-ahead `(?=...)` for matching, because the patterns can overlap.